# Error al importar graphviz y pydot

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

Muy buenas tardes, espero se encuentren muy bien.

Me encuentro haciendo un ejercicio de redes neuronales en el que estoy utilizando keras de tensorflow, al momento de graficar me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> ('You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) ', 'for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.')

Sin embargo, ya cuento con dichas librerías instaladas y actualizadas. A continuación la evidencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asimismo, ya instalé graphviz desde la URL que me recomienda el mensaje. Agradezco me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Que IDE estas utilizando?

Comment: Hola, estoy utilizando un notebook en Jupyter